# Find 20 latest tweets from million people you are following on twitter

Tags: algorithm, scalability, bigdata

The question was go through the entire design approach of various things you would do in your web application so that if you are following millions of people on twitter and when you check for the latest 20 tweets you find it in least time and putting least load on resources. It was a open ended design question about the entire stack.

My Answer not complete(as i was not able to answer this completely)

1. Since we are talking of millions of users then we have to shard the database, according to the user geographic locations , This answer was not accepted as in twitter you really don't follow people in same location. 
   What are better ways in which this can be achieved ?
2. Since mostly the 20 latest tweets are most important then for each user maintain a cache(linkedlist) which has the latest tweets according to the time they arrived.
   This wasn't accepted either.

In general i am weak in these kinds of design problems and would like to know how would you go about solving them ?

Comment: Just so you know. I think caching is one of the best ways to achieve this goal. Since you are already following millions of people, the additional data saved for caching for a single user is marginal. And caching is way faster, because when someone tweets, a tweet has to be accommodated in the cache of every person just once, instead of every time you request your latest 20 tweets.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter has evolved for several years and I believe it's one of the most sophisticatedly designed data system. In such a sophisticated system, many optimizations may have been done for different type of users(depending on their tweet frequency, number of following and followers).

Users who follow millions of people are undoubtedly a very special kind, and may not be too many. I think for these users, a sensible design is to update your timeline data in a cache every time your followings post a tweet, and archive the very old ones. So it return you the cache instantly every time you request your timeline.

Above is only the most simple and straightforward way to make the system works for you. In reality, more measures have to be considered in design, such as how many users do follow millions of people, how frequently these users refresh, etc.